# Angular.js idiom for disabling button when textarea is blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I want a button to be disabled unless text is present in a textarea. Here is what I have tried:

```
<textarea ng-model="shipment_ids"></textarea>
<button ng-click="do_something" ng-disabled="shipment_ids.length"></button>
```

However, the button is enabled no matter what.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you want the opposite of what your code states. Something like:

```
<textarea ng-model="shipment_ids"></textarea>
<button ng-click="do_something" ng-disabled="!shipment_ids">Click me</button>
```

Example [on JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/spencerooni/5adfs/).

Comment: This fixed my problem. It looks like I should have re-visited my assumption that the button wasn't being disabled when I typed text in the textarea.